# Express - response middleware is not used

Tags: node.js, express

```
var log = console.log
var responseLogMiddleware = function(req, res, next) {
  log("inside the response middleware")
  res.send()
}
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.status(404)
  res.body = {"status" : "notDone"}
})
app.use(responseLogMiddleware)

app.listen(8003);
```

I expected the above error to be logged via `responseLogMiddleware`. But,neither the logger is printing the logs nor the response is sent back.

I am not using `res.json` (or) `res.send`, since it flushes out the response bypassing the middlewares.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var log = console.log
var responseLogMiddleware = function(req, res, next) {
    log("inside the response middleware");
    return res.send();
}

app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.status(404)
  res.body = {"status" : "notDone"};
  next();
})
app.use(responseLogMiddleware);
```

You should use `next()` topass control to the next handler(`responseLogMiddleware`). And you should put `app.use(responseLogMiddleware)` after all your router.

Comment: yes BlackMamba, that works.. but it is not practical since i have hundreds of  existing route methods, and adding `next` to all of them adds burden to me

Comment: @MadhavanKumar I think this is the only way.

Answer (score 0):

try this

`app.use('/',responseLogMiddleware)`

You need to link your middleware with some route path because its a router level middleware

for all routes you have to use

`app.use('*',responseLogMiddleware)`

Comment: it is not a router level middleware.. it is meant to intercept all responses.

Comment: You have to use * to catch all routes